# How to select and assign to a specific $key, a specific $value, among multiple choices?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with multiple columns, from which I need to select all of them of each record, and to create a specific `$key=>$value` from it.
for example

**TABLE**

```
  ID  |  group_cat |  group_sec  |  group_name  | enabled | sent
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1  |      C     |    sct_a   |  Project_A   |    1    |  no
   2  |      C     |    sct_b   |  Project_B   |    1    |  no
   3  |      P     |    sct_c   |  Moderators  |    1    |  no
   4  |      C     |    sct_d   |  Ambassad    |    1    |  no
   5  |      P     |    sct_e   |  PMP         |    0    |  no
```

The MySQL query I need is `"SELECT * FROM groups WHERE sent = 'no' "`
By PHP is

**PHP Code**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `groups` WHERE `sent`= 'no' ";
$sth = $sql->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();

while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    foreach($row as $key => $value) { $$key = $value; }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Here my question:
I need that the `$key` is from the column `'group_sec`' and the related `$value` is from the column `'group_name'`. So that the couple `$$key=>$value` can return this result (for instance)

```
echo $sec_b;
```

returns: **Project_B**

Could you help me to get this done please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: dosn't each loop turn overwrite the previous rows vars with `foreach($row as $key => $value) { $$key = $value; }`

Comment: Why do you want to use variable variables? Sounds like a pretty broken design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job for you:

```
${$row['group_sec']} = $row['group_name'];
echo $sct_b;
```

Output:

```
Project_B
```

You would use this in your while loop (the foreach can probably be deleted):

```
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ${$row['group_sec']} = $row['group_name'];
    ...
    // do something with $sct_b
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, if your column names might change, but the positions will stay the same, you can use

```
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    ${$row[2]} = $row[3];
    ...
    // do something with $sct_b
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 Yeah, I was about to provide same solution. But it would be nice if you can demonstrate where to put this. I suspect OP will put it in the foreach loop instead of the while loop

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen fair comment. I've updated the post. Feel free to edit if you feel it needs more.

Comment: It seems like a config table with unique values for group_sec. I hope OP knows what he is doing. But as long as group_sec values are unique, should be fine :)

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen agreed. I've yet to see a good reason to use variable variables.

Comment: Hi @Nick thanks a lot for the help. It work. However my idea was a bit different and perhaps it was not clear from the initial post.
I would like to do in a way that: if ever I change the names of the columns, I have not to re-open the file(s) to update them into the files as well. That's why I avoided the format "${$row['group_sec']} = $row['group_name'];" you validly suggested

Comment: @TormyVanCool  If you change the names of the columns, how will the code know which column's value to assign to which variable? If you don't change the position of the columns, I guess you could use `$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` and `${$row[2]} = $row[3];` or something similar?

Comment: @Nick right, column position never change. Great suggestion. Thanks a million

Comment: @Nick I voted green because your last suggestion  is what I needed. Please can you eventually edit your answer inserting this suggestion? I think it will be more clear for anybody else is needing for this solution.
Tanks a lot :)

Comment: @TormyVanCool Done! Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an array  based on key and value you prefer using `$row['group_sec']` for key and `$row['group_name']` eg:

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `groups` WHERE `sent`= 'no' ";
  $sth = $sql->prepare($query);
  $sth->execute();

  while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

      $myArray[$row['group_sec']] = $row['group_name'];
  }
```

and you can see the result

```
 foreach($myArray as  $key => $value){
  echo  $key . ' - ' . $value . '<br>';

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE sent= 'no'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  $list=[];
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $list{$row['group_sec']} = $row['group_name'];
   }
}
```